# Don't get expected results from Python's super

Tags: python

From my understanding, the function `super` should allow a Class that is nested within another to access its parent's 'self'.  I may be wrong on this, but here is a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class Test:
     def __init__(self):
         self.message = "Hello World"
     class Print:
         def __init__(self):
             print super(Test, self).message


this = Test()
this.Print()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home1/users/joe.borg/<ipython-input-3-3eb5db70be43> in <module>()
----> 1 this.Print()

/home1/users/joe.borg/<ipython-input-1-cee67a2914c3> in __init__(self)
      4     class Print:
      5         def __init__(self):
----> 6             print super(Test, self).message
      7 

TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

Comment: Why do you think you want to nest classes like that?

Comment: Your understanding of `super()` is simply wrong, you may want to start from the [official doc](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super). Even thouhg `super()` might be tricky, it's a topic well covered arount the internet.

Comment: To me, there is a lot of interest in nesting classes.  Just an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78799/is-there-a-benefit-to-defining-a-class-inside-another-class-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the desired results like this:

```
class Test(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.message = "Hello World"
class Print(Test):
         def __init__(self):
             print super(Print, self).message
```

Answer (score 5):

`super` is supposed to be used to call the next method in the [mro](http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.3/mro/) (method resolution order) of a given class (which is usually the method from the parent class). That's something completely different to what you're trying to do.

In addition to this, your classes are old-style classes (they don't subclass object), so `super` complains because it only works with new-style classes.

Answer (score 4):

The error you get spurs from the fact that `super` only works with new-style classes, i.e. classes that explicitly extend `object`.

Besides, `super` [allows you to delegate method calls to a parent or sibling class in a linearized inheritance tree](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super). However, nested classes are not bound by an inheritance relationship; so, even if you fixed the error (i.e. allowing `Test` and `Print` to extend `object`), `super` would not work in this case.