# How to organise Python related classes

Tags: python, oop

I have currently this structure inside a file:

```
class Foo:
    __init__(self): 
       pass

class FooType(object):
    __init__(self, value):
       _foo = value
    __str__(self):
       print ">>%s<<" % self._foo

class FooException(Exception):
    pass
```

All the above classes are tightly related. My master class will have types, structures, enums all declared as a separated class with the prefix `Foo`. And as usual a custom exception should be declared for `Foo`. At the end of the day I will have a lot of related classes at the same level of other classes.

Is there a proper way to get a better structure? Perhaps a `namespace` can help, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, the idiomatic way to do namespaces is to use different modules. You should name your file `foo.py`, and then import that. Then you use it with `foo.Exception` and `foo.Type`. If you need to have a more complex module that needs more than one file, you should make a folder called `foo` and put an `__init__.py` file along with your other components of the module. For further documentation on using modules, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

Another solution is to use nested classes to provide a namespace. The chosen answer to [this question about nested classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78799/is-there-a-benefit-to-defining-a-class-inside-another-class-in-python) recommends them for the purpose of namespacing.

Comment: Well, should I use nested classes for static structures and types?

Comment: @nowox They can be class variables of the outer class, which makes it essentially just a namespace. I haven't done it more than once before, so I don't really know all the complexities.

Answer (score 1):

You could organize your classes in [modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), just like the Python standard library does.