# “Python NameError: name is not defined” for class

Tags: python, class, telegram-bot

I am having difficulty fully defining the class in my Python code. I have played around with it, but have had no luck.

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, \
    ConversationHandler, MessageHandler, BaseFilter, run_async, Filters
     

class TelegramBot:
    class PrivateUserFilter(BaseFilter):
        def __init__(self, user_id):
            self.user_id = int(user_id)

        def filter(self, message):
            return message.from_user.id == self.user_id

    def __init__(self, token: str, allowed_user_id): 
        self.updater = Updater(token=token)
        self.dispatcher = self.updater.dispatcher
        self.private_filter = PrivateUserFilter(allowed_user_id)
        self._prepare()
```

It's throwing the following exception:

```
~\OneDrive - yyy\..\core\telegrambot.py in __init__(self, token, allowed_user_id)
---> 44         self.private_filter = PrivateUserFilter(allowed_user_id)
     45         self._prepare()
     46 

NameError: name 'PrivateUserFilter' is not defined
```

Comment: `TelegramBot.PrivateUserFilter`? But do you really need to define the class `PrivateUserFilter` in the class `TelegramBot`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a benefit to defining a class inside another class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78799/is-there-a-benefit-to-defining-a-class-inside-another-class-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You're putting a class inside an other class. This means the "inside" class is only available as an *attribute* on the first.

And while some some systems make use of such nested classes e.g. Django somewhat famously uses nested classes for some types of meta-information of models and forms, here it seems completely useless.

Just move `PrivateUserFilter` to the toplevel, next to the other class.

Comment: I moved PrivateUserFilter to the toplevel, next to the other class and get now the following error: TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class PrivateUserFilter with abstract methods __call__

Comment: That's an API misuse. According to the documentation for `BaseFilter`: "If you want to create your own filters create a class inheriting from either `MessageFilter` or `UpdateFilter` and implement a `filter()` method that returns a boolean: `True` if the message should be handled, `False` otherwise."

Answer (score 0):

Change `self.private_filter = PrivateUserFilter(allowed_user_id)` to `self.private_filter = self.PrivateUserFilter(allowed_user_id)`.

Edit: can also use `TelegramBot` instead of `self`.

Think of it like namespaces, you'll only be able to call the inner class if you reference the outer one.

Comment: thanks, that helped. I get now another error: 
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class PrivateUserFilter with abstract methods __call__

Comment: Is the error pointing to somewhere else in the code? Have you defined other dunder methods? Is the error coming from: `self._prepare()` ?