# Python: subclass with more init parameters as argument

Tags: python, class, arguments

I have a problem that I cannot describe well, but I'll try. I'm trying to create my http server with own protocol used to process commands in get requests.

But I need somehow pass used protocol to class `HttpServer` from `MyServer`, which is only referenced as argument of class initializer of `ThreadingSimpleServer`. But it is only passed as class reference.

Right now, my question is, how should I extend the initializer of `HttpServer` to take the protocol class argument, and how to pass this argument through `ThreadingSimpleServer` initializer to make it work.

```
import socketserver
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import socketserver
import threading

class Protocol():
    def processGetReq(self):
        pass

class MyServer():

    def __init__(self, protocol: Protocol, srvr_ip="127.0.0.1", srvr_port=10001):
        self.srvr_addr = (srvr_ip, srvr_port)
        self.protocol = protocol

    def start(self):
        self.server = self.ThreadingSimpleServer(self.srvr_addr, RequestHandlerClass=self.HttpServer)
        self._server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._handle_requests)
        self._server_thread.start()

    def _handle_requests(self):
        while 1:
            self.server.handle_request()

    def serveForever(self):
        self._server_thread.join()

    class HttpServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

        def __init__(self, request: bytes, client_address: tuple[str, int], server: socketserver.BaseServer) -> None:
            super().__init__(request, client_address, server)


        def do_GET(self):
            self.protocol.processGetReq()
            self._set_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b"OK, get")

    class ThreadingSimpleServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
        pass

    
##################################################################
#####################         START         ######################
##################################################################


server = MyServer(SomeProtocol()) # Here would be some protocol subclass of baseclass Protocol
server.start()

print("Server ready!")

server.serveForever()
```

Comment: You're importing a class HTTPServer from the http.server modeule, and then you're defining a new class with the same name. So, you're going to have http.server.HTTPServer objects, and MyServer.HTTPServer objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a benefit to defining a class inside another class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78799/is-there-a-benefit-to-defining-a-class-inside-another-class-in-python), in particular https://stackoverflow.com/a/49812827/15032126